# Callback Function Not Firing On Selection In Media Uploader

Tags: theme-development, uploads, media

I'm studying theme development and am working on some code for a media uploader that can be used to add a picture. The file frame is opening (and I've called `wp_enqueue_media();` for that to be the case), but nothing happens after the picture is selected.

I think I'm missing something simple and, frankly, I'm going crazy looking for it. Could anyone help me out?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var mediaUploader;

  $('#upload-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(mediaUploader){
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }

    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose a profile picture',
      button: {
        text: 'Choose Picture'
      },
      multiple: false
    });

    //This alert fires.
    alert("First message.");

    $(mediaUploader).on('select', function(){
      //This alert does not fire.
      alert("Second message.");
    });

    mediaUploader.open();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassing.

```
$(mediaUploader).on('select', function(){
```

Should be:

```
mediaUploader.on('select', function(){
```

In case anybody stumbles upon this, $({item}) looks for the item in the DOM, not the variable of the same name in the previous code. Since the select event isn't firing in the DOM, the callback function isn't going to fire either.